# $route.query mysteriously being set

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

#### Vue 2.6.12

I'm using `router.beforeEach` in my router to log `to.query` along my !auth / auth / entryUrl logic.

It starts out empty, but right before the operative `next()` it has an object (a filters object in my store). I'm mystified how it's getting set as I'm not doing it intentionally and don't know how to pinpoint the source.

Rereshing the page and logging this.$route.query in `beforeCreate()` should return an empty object but it's the filter object.

On other pages, logging this.$route.query returns {} as I would expect.

#### router/index

**(tips on how to refactor this for efficiency welcome)**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import AddItem from "../views/AddItem";
import store from "../store/index";
...

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "AppLogin",
    component: AppLogin,
    meta: { requiresAuth: false },
  },
  {
    path: "/art-inventory",
    name: "ArtInventory",
    component: ArtInventory,
    meta: { requiresAuth: true },
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    redirect: { name: "ArtInventory" },
    meta: { requiresAuth: false },
  },
  {
    path: "*",
    redirect: "/404",
    component: NotFound,
    meta: { requiresAuth: false },
  },
  {
    path: "/404",
    name: "404",
    component: NotFound,
    meta: { requiresAuth: false },
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});

let entryUrl = null;
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.log(to.query); // empty {}
  let localStorageUserData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
  let storeUserData = store.getters.getUserData;
  let userData = localStorageUserData || storeUserData;
  let isAuthenticated = userData.token !== "" && userData.token !== undefined;

  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      if (to.name !== "AppLogin" && to.name !== "ArtInventory") {
        entryUrl = to.fullPath;
      }
      if (to.name !== "AppLogin") {
        next({ name: "AppLogin" });
      }
    } else if (entryUrl) {
      let url = entryUrl;
      entryUrl = null;
      window.location.href = url;
    } else {
      console.log(to.query); // not empty {...}

      next();
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

export default router;
```

Comment: Hi, Please share some code.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari added above.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari I figured out where it was coming from. I didn't realize my beforeEach in router was being hit multiple times during app initialization and I was using some bad logic. I thought if object ===  {} return false0.